# 2D array slicing by float value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, slice

I want to slice an array of [x,y] coordinate pairs by x value in Python 3.x, in a similar way to the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027885/slice-list-of-floats-by-value-in-python) question but with coordinates rather than a 1d list.

For example for the (numpy) array of coordinates I want a function like:

```
coords = np.array([[1.5,10],[2.5,20],[3.5,30],[4.5,40],[5.5,50]])
def slice_coords_by_x(xmin, xmax, arr):
    *some function*
slice_coords_by_x(2, 4, arr)
>>>[[2.5,20],[3.5,30]]
```

Not overly fussy if the solution is inclusive or exclusive of xmin and xmax since i'll be using this over a large range of over 1000 or so.

Comment: So you basically want to filter? Is it guaranteed that the `x` coordinates are ordered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice and create a mask with such min-max limits and thus select rows with [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
def slice_coords_by_x(arr, xmin, xmax):
    return arr[(arr[:,0] >= xmin) & (arr[:,0] <= xmax)]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [43]: arr
Out[43]: 
array([[  1.5,  10. ],
       [  2.5,  20. ],
       [  3.5,  30. ],
       [  4.5,  40. ],
       [  5.5,  50. ]])

In [44]: slice_coords_by_x(arr, xmin=2, xmax=4)
Out[44]: 
array([[  2.5,  20. ],
       [  3.5,  30. ]])

In [45]: slice_coords_by_x(arr, xmin=1, xmax=5)
Out[45]: 
array([[  1.5,  10. ],
       [  2.5,  20. ],
       [  3.5,  30. ],
       [  4.5,  40. ]])
```

Comment: Appreciated all the answers thanks all- chose this one purely because it doesn't depend on another package and it retains the numpy array type over Python's own array

Answer (score 2):

Without `numpy`, you could use `bisect` for this, to find insertion point. Note that the parameter is a list (I was adding `None` as second parameter as seen in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908047/using-bisect-in-a-list-of-tuples), but it's not useful).

```
import bisect

coords = [[1.5,10],[2.5,20],[3.5,30],[4.5,40],[5.5,50]]

def slice_coords_by_x(lower,upper,arr):
    l=bisect.bisect_left(arr,[lower])
    u=bisect.bisect_right(arr,[upper])
    return arr[l:u]

print(slice_coords_by_x(2,4,coords))
```

result:

```
[[2.5, 20], [3.5, 30]]
```

`bisect` requires that the list is sorted (which seems to be the case) or that won't work.

Comment: Can't you simply use `[lower]` instead of `[lower,None]`? At least for `bisect_left`?

Comment: nope: `TypeError: unorderable types: list() < int()`

Comment: but `[lower]` is still a `list`.

Comment: furthermore given your `lower = 2` and there is a point `[2,3]`, wouldn't that crash on a comparison between `3` and `None`?

Comment: it works with `None`, but that's not useful, so I edited it out.

Comment: given I query `bisect.bisect_left(arr,[2.5,None])`, I get `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()`... With `arr` the one defined above.

Comment: Funny. So the answer I linked to telling to put `None` is just _wrong_. Wait: it must be python 2 only, as you were able to compare strings with ints, etc... not anymore in python 3.

Answer (score 2):

## Unordered

If the given list of points are unordered, you can use a `filter`, and materialize with `list`:

```
def slice_coords_by_x(xmin,xmax,arr):
    return list(filter(lambda p: xmin < p[0] < xmax,arr))
```

You can evidently feed your sorted list to this as well, but it will take considerably more time than the next approach.

## Sorted list

Given the points are **sorted by x-coordinate**, you can use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) package:

```
def slice_coords_by_x(xmin,xmax,arr):
    left = bisect.bisect_left(arr,[xmin])
    right = bisect.bisect_right(arr,[xmax])
    return arr[left:right]
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't simply

```
def slice_coords_by_x(xmin, xmax, arr):
    return [i for i in arr if xmin <= i[0] and i[0] <= xmax]
```

do the trick? It's readable, fast and accessible.

This list can be sorted or even pass an array, but the approach should be accessible enough to be changed to any needs.

Comment: `if xmin <= i[0] and i[0] <= xmax` => `if xmin <= i[0] <= xmax` is even better. Willem answer already covers that, though.

Comment: `if xmin <= i[0] and i[0] <= xmax` and `if xmin <=  i[0] <= xmax` are actually one and the same thing.

Comment: probably, but the latter is more "pythonic".

Comment: Also I am not sure, that Willems answer is any kind of superior to mine. So why shouldn't I write a way easier to read and understand? PS.: I wrote the answer before Willem, I actually typed it as a comment before, deleted it, reformated it and saved it and I didn't saw Willems answer before.

Comment: You have to be more aggressive when answering ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre PS.: The answer you told me is already stating my answer, is by the way not pythonic at all, at least if you refer to PEP 8.